# keyPressed() function not rendering jump smoothly

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I just started using p5.js, I like the simplicity but there's one thing I can not grasp.

I set up the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/daqsxb5z/2/):

```
function Player(location, width, height, speed, weight) {
    this.pos = location;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.velocity = speed;
    this.mass = weight;
    this.grav = new p5.Vector(0, this.mass * 10);
}

function Wall(location, width, height) {
    this.pos = location;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

var p1 = new Player(new p5.Vector(-100, 0), 50, 70, new p5.Vector(0, 0), 1);
var wall1 = new Wall(new p5.Vector(100, -100), 50, 50);
var collision = false;
var jump = new p5.Vector(0, -10);

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 500);
    background(100);
}

function draw() {
    // Set zero-point
    translate(-p1.pos.x * 0.95 + 100, height - p1.height);

    // Apply gravity if p1 is not touching object
    if (p1.pos.y > 0) {
        // Do not apply p1.grav
        collision = true;
    } else {
        p1.pos.add(p1.grav);
        collision = false;
    }

    noStroke();
    fill(55, 37, 73);
    background(100);
    rect(p1.pos.x, p1.pos.y, p1.width, p1.height);
    rect(wall1.pos.x, wall1.pos.y, wall1.width, wall1.height);

    if (p1.pos.x < -p1.width * 2) {
        p1.velocity.x = 10;
        p1.pos.add(p1.velocity.x);
    } else {
        if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
            p1.velocity.x = 5;
            p1.pos.sub(p1.velocity.x);
        } else if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
            p1.velocity.x = 5;
            p1.pos.add(p1.velocity.x);
        }
    }
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (key == ' ') {
        p1.pos.y += jump.y;
    }
}
```

So the final `keyPressed()` function is where the problem lies. Whenever the user presses space, I want the Player to "jump", basically adding a y-velocity to the object. The state it is in right now is simplified, it basically sets the position to whatever `jump.y` is. (*It doesn't seem to be working right now, which is rather odd, because it did before.*) That problem is resolved.

Anyways, that is not the main issue. The main issue is that (when it did work), the jump would be not animated at all, and basically just changed the position of the p1 object, as I described before (and how it should work as the code is right now), but I ultimately want the jump to be a much nicer animation, similar to the "walking" animation, which is rather smooth.

I already tried replacing `p1.pos.y += jump.y;` with something like

```
p1.velocity.y = jump.y;
p1.pos.y += p1.velocity.y;
```

but I got similar results.

I think this might be because the `draw()` function is repetitive, and the `keyPressed()` function isn't. I also tried putting the function inside of `draw()` but this didn't work.

I'm really lost here.

EDIT: [Made an MCVE](https://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/og46fmLx/2/)

Comment: Also figured out why it wasn't jumping, -10 is apparently too small for a noticable jump.y

Answer (score 2):

You need a few things:

**Step 1:** If you want stuff to fall, you're going to need gravity. You can think of gravity as acceleration downwards, which in your code would be decreasing `velocity.y` by some constant. Of course, you also have to actually add this `velocity.y` to the player movement. Right now you only ever add `velocity.x`.

**Step 2:** If you want stuff to *stop* falling, you're going to need some logic that stops the player's downward movement. This could be as simple as checking the player's Y position, or you might get more advanced and check against game objects. In any case you're going to have to implement something that stops you from falling off the screen.

**Step 3:** Once you have those two things, you can fix your `keyPressed()` function by simply setting the `velocity.y` value to some value. You might also want a check in here to prevent the player from jumping in the air.

The moral of the story is: you have to break your problem down into smaller steps, and then work on one of those steps at a time. If you get stuck, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: The first 2 steps are actually there already, have a look at the second statement of `draw()`. However, the syntax should probably be `p1.pos.y` instead of `p1.pos`. So I'll look into that. Plus, I also created a mechanism to detect collision, with `var collision`. But thanks for your answer, it's actually quite helpful. After a couple of hours of coding, you stop seeing your mistakes :)

Comment: Made an MCVE over here https://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/og46fmLx/1/, it demonstrates my problem correctly. The jump is basically instantaneous, whereas the applied gravity is smooth. How can this happen?

Comment: @YSbakker If you have another question, you should probably just post a new question. But I think your problem is that you don't **decrease** your velocity. You just set it equal to `5` immediately. You'll probably find that `100` is too large a value for jump, the only reason it works is because you immediately cancel the velocity and set it to `5`.

Comment: It's not a different question, this was my initial problem. The only other problem I had was that the player wouldn't visually jump, but it was because the jump.y was too small. How could I decrease the velocity gradually? Why doesn't it behave the same as in the draw function, where I also set the velocity to 3 immediately? EDIT: I'm sorry if my question confused you, I probably should have stated more clearly what the actual problem was, instead of stating 2 problems.

Comment: @YSbakker I'm not confused. I understand exactly what your code does, and I'm trying to explain the problem. I first stated it in different steps because in fact you don't have the first two steps. You might think you do, but you're missing some vital pieces to get it working. You would decrease it by subtracting something from it, not setting it to a completely new value. Something like this: `ySpeed -= gravity;` where `ySpeed` is your velocity and `gravity` is some constant that you define. What you're doing is this: `ySpeed = 5` which isn't enough to make it work like gravity.

Comment: @YSbakker Think about how this works in reality. You have a speed and an acceleration. Your speed is contantly changed by your acceleration, and your acceleration is constantly changed by gravity (and other stuff, but focus on gravity for now). You speed doesn't magically become some other number without being accelerated. You need to capture that with your variables.

Comment: @YSbakker Now, Stack Overflow really isn't designed for this type of back and forth, which is why I asked you to post a new question if you still can't get it working. While putting together a new [mcve], you might want to clean up your code so it's more obvious exactly what's going on, but that's really up to you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that's the question I was aiming at. I understand what you're saying.